# When I use the -play command,I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord music bot and when I use the -play command which is the only one I've created so far it gives me this error is console

```
"(node:20336) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)"
```

which when I do, I get this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at (program) (<eval>/VM46947595:1:8)
```

as a result, I am very confused

also here's the code

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { Message } = require('discord.js');

const queue = new Map();

modulue.exports = {
        name: 'play',
    aliases:['skip', 'stop', 'pause', 'resume'],
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'dat jazz baby',
    async execute(Message, args, cmd, client, Discord){

        const voice_channel = Message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('you ain\'t in a voice channel dummy');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(Message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('can\'t talk');

        const server_queue = queue.get(Message.guild.id);

        if (Message.content === prefix + play){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('no args. You keep this up and Mark Zukerberg could die of ligma');
            let song = {};

            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])){
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = {title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url};
            } else {
                const video_finder = async (query) => {
                    const videoresult = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (videoresult.videos.length > 0) ? videoresult.videos[0] : null;
                }
                const song_info = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = title; video.title, url; video.url }
                else {
                    return Message.channel.send('damn so no maidens or vidjas');
                } 
            }


            if (!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    textChannel: message.channel,
                    voiceChannel: voice_channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: [],
                }
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push.push(song)

                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    play(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    return message.channel.send(err);
                    message.channel.send('I fell and I can\'t get up\(try again\)');
                    throw err;  // this will throw the error to the console
                }
            } else {
                server_queue.song.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue`);
            }
    }
        }
}      

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const server_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        server_queue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
        const stream = ytdl(song.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
        song_queue.connection.play(stream, { Seek: 0, volume: 0.5})
        .on(finish, () => {
            server_queue.songs.shift();
            video_player(guild, server_queue.songs[0]);
        })
        
        

}
```

I didn't exactly expect it to work, but seeing as I'm pretty new to coding I'm kinda helpless

Answer (score 0):

The error shown in your message is not an error, it's a module `DeprecationError`. I'm pretty sure that's not causing the problem. The real error is the `SyntaxError`.

Is your code in Typescript (TS)?

(ytdl-core is a node js dependency, so you have to use `require` unless you are using TS)

Comment: It's not in typescript, and after some checking it said I needed to "Use messageCreate"
but since there's not anywhere this applies to in the code I'm confused again.

Comment: hmm. I didn't run the code actually on my local machine, but I answered purely based on what error was given.